# get the image name CodeNameOne

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to get a list of objects from database 
i'm 100% that i retreive the data but the list so my php code seems to be good

```
    public ArrayList<Categorie> getListCategorie() {
     ArrayList<Categorie> listcategories = new ArrayList<>();


    ConnectionRequest con2 = new ConnectionRequest();
    con2.setUrl("http://localhost/pidev2017/selectcategorie.php");
    con2.addResponseListener(new ActionListener<NetworkEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(NetworkEvent evt) {
        try {
        JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
        Map<String, Object> catefories = j.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader(new String(con2.getResponseData()).toCharArray()));
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) catefories.get("Categorie");
        for (Map<String, Object> obj : list) {
            Categorie categorie = new Categorie();
            categorie.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.get("id").toString()));
            categorie.setNomCategorie(obj.get("nomCategorie").toString());
            listcategories.add(categorie);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
        }

    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con2);
    return listcategories;
}
```

when i want to fetch my result "listcategories" i found that is empty

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con2);
```

to

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(con2);
```

It's possible that you try to get the result before the data has been fetched.